# How to add CIDRs from files to set in best way?

Tags: shell-script, awk, openwrt, nftables

So I have several files which contain `CIDR` entries (such as `1.1.1.0/24`). The task is to add entries from these files to one `NFTables` set using a bash script. In doing so, I am limited to `OpenWRT` utilities.

The catch is that there can be many entries in these files and they can exhaust the limit of **4096 characters per command**. And also these files are automatically updated by `cron`, so a set needs to be periodically erased and re-filled as well.

It seems to me that there is an easier way to do this than I have already done it. I also want to reduce the execution time of this mess. Here is my attempt to do this.

```bash
nft add element $TARGET_SET { $(awk '{print $1 ", "}' "$CUSTOM_CIDRS_FILE") }
```

Here's another question, if my file has a very large number of entries, will I overcome this limit of 4096 characters per command? And one last question, will it take a very long time to form a set if I add entries one at a time in a loop?

I'm waiting primarily for answers with good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can build up a string to execute that can be held below a
particular length; this will doubtless be more efficient than an
`xargs` that must fork an `echo ... | tr` pipeline.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
{
    len = length()
    if (len > limit) {
        if (length(outbuf)) {
            system("echo " ENVIRON["TARGET_SET"] outbuf)
        }
        outbuf = $0
        # the limit will be 4096 minus the length of the rest of
        # the command and if the 4096 is kern.argmax then you
        # may need to subtract even more to account for the
        # length of the environment variables!
        limit = 6
    } else {
        # join another field to output buffer
        outbuf = outbuf "," $0
    }
    # the plus is for the length of the field joiner
    limit -= len + 1
}
END {
    if (length(outbuf)) {
        system("echo " ENVIRON["TARGET_SET"] outbuf)
    }
}
```

The `"echo "` in this script are for testing, one would presumably
instead run the suitable `nft ...` command. `TARGET_SET` must be
exported so that `awk` can read it from the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Where have you read about a 4096 character limit in nftables commands? If I have a list of 4000 CIDR ranges (that's almost 64,000 characters), I can run your command without errors:

```
# wc -l ranges.txt
400.0 ranges.txt
# export TARGET_SET=example_set
# export CUSTOM_CIDRS_FILE=ranges.txt
# nft add set ip filter $TARGET_SET { type ipv4_addr\; flags interval\; }
# nft add element $TARGET_SET { $(awk '{print $1 ", "}' "$CUSTOM_CIDRS_FILE") }
```

The `nft add` commands run in about 0.003 seconds with 4000 elements.

It seems as if at some point we might run into Linux command line length limits, in which case we could batch things up. This will add elements in batches of 1000:

```
xargs -n1000 sh -c '
  nft add element ip filter $TARGET_SET { $(
    echo "$@" | tr " " ","
  ) }' -- < $CUSTOM_CIDRS_FILE
```

(Note that the above assumes that `TARGET_SET` is an environment variable, not a shell variable.)

This runs in about 0.1 seconds for the same 4000 elements.

Comment: perhaps the 4096 is for `kern.argmax` which might be set lower on a system with not much memory for various reasons

Comment: ...in which case the second part of this answer is exactly what you need :).